# Second socket write does not appear to send to network

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm creating a simple network client. It reads a text file and puts each line to the network.
At the far end, there's a server which reads the incoming line and responds with a CSV text line.

The outgoing file I'm using for testing is simple:

6216448319,Richard Nixon,Log In
6216448319,Richard Nixon,Log Out

The response should be, "Logged In." followed by "Logged Out."

The first line processes perfectly, but although the second line appears to be written to the socket, The server never sees an incoming message. I've done my best to follow the documentation and various tutorials on line, but nothing I've seen seems to exhibit the same behavior. What am I missing?

If I send each line in its own file, the server responds correctly.

```
protected Integer call() {
    LOG.info("Starting spooler for file {}, address {}:{}", spoolFile, ipAddress, port);
    InetAddress server = null;
    try {
        server = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
        LOG.info("IP Address: {}", server.getHostAddress());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unknown host: {}", ipAddress, e);
    }
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(server, port);
         BufferedWriter socketWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
         //PrintWriter socketWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
         BufferedReader socketReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(spoolFile)))
    ) {
        // Read the spool file line by line and put it out on the wire.
        String line;
        while ((line = fileReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                LOG.error("Spool has been cancelled.");
                break;
            }
            line = line.trim();
            LOG.info("OUT({}): [{}]", line.length(), line);
            //Wait until the channel has successfully written out the line.
            LOG.info("Socket is {} for write.", socket.isConnected() ? "connected" : "not connected");
            socketWriter.write(line);
            socketWriter.flush();
            TalkmanMessage outMessage = new TalkmanMessage(line);
            outMessageList.add(outMessage);
            // Wait for the network to respond.
            // Apparently, readline() blocks until a message is received.
            LOG.info("Waiting for response...");
            LOG.info("Socket is {} for read.", socket.isConnected() ? "connected" : "not connected");
            String msg = socketReader.readLine();
            LOG.info("IN({}): [{}]", msg == null ? null : msg.length(), msg);
            TalkmanMessage inMessage = new TalkmanMessage(msg);
            inMessage.setDelay(
                    Duration.between(outMessage.getTime(), inMessage.getTime()).toNanos());
            inMessageList.add(inMessage);
            //The readline() seems to leave a non-printing byte in the socket. Read that out.
            int leftOver;
            do {
                LOG.info("Socket is {} for EOL", socket.isConnected() ? "connected." : "not connected");
                leftOver = socketReader.read();
                LOG.info("Read {} from socket.", leftOver);
            } while (leftOver > -1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Unable to read from file/write to .", e);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The logging commands produce the following output:

```
OUT(29): [6216448319,Richard Nixon,Log In] 
Socket is connected for write.
Waiting for response... 
Socket is connected for read. 
IN(12): ["Logged in."]
Socket is connected for EOL 
Read 13 from socket. S
Socket is connected for EOL 
Read 10 from socket. 
Socket is connected for EOL 
Read -1 from socket. 
OUT(30): [6216448319,Richard Nixon,Log Out] 
Socket is connected for write. 
Waiting for response... 
Socket is connected for read. IN(null): [null] 
Socket is connected for EOL 
Read -1 from socket.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're ignoring end of stream. Once `read()` has returned -1, the connection is closed.
2. You are wrong to be continually testing `socket.isConnected()`. It doesn't magically become false. It isn't a test for peer disconnect.
3. Surely you should be writing *lines* to the peer? i.e. calling `newLine()` after sending every line?
4. And in fact you should just be copying *bytes*, not reading lines, removing/restoring line terminators, trimming, etc. With streams, not readers and writers.
5. And if you're spooling, why are you expecting a response for every line? The essence of spooling is that you just write. And the data being returned (below) in no wise suggests that it is a response per line.
6. You seem to be trying to read EOL, which has already been removed by `newLine()`. See the Javadoc. This doesn't make sense. And you're also trying to do it by reading until end of stream, on every line you send, which makes even less sense.
7. What the server has sent you is as follows:

   ```
   IN(12): ["Logged in."]<some line terminator, probably but not certainly CR LF because of below>
   S <CR><LF>
   ```

   It has then closed the connection.

I suggest you need to thoroughly review the application protocol.

Comment: Your last suggestion was the key. There was no protocol, per se, but due to legacy constraints, the server was expecting the socket to be closed after each response and a new socket created before each transmission.

Comment: No. The server is *closing* the socket after each response, not just 'expecting'. That's why `read()` at the client returned -1.